# Using a recursive call in If-condition in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I have written a function to perform lasso regression using coordinate descent.

The code is as follows:

```
def lasso_cyclical_coordinate_descent(feature_matrix, output, weights, l1_penalty, tolerance):
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        old_weights_i = weights[i]
        weights[i] = lasso_coordinate_descent_step(i, feature_matrix, output, weights, l1_penalty)
        diff = []
        diff.append(abs(old_weights_i - weights[i]))
    if max(diff) > tolerance:
        weights = lasso_cyclical_coordinate_descent(feature_matrix, output, weights, l1_penalty, tolerance)
    return weights
```

My thinking here was that running a recursive call inside an If-condition will result in the weights being returned only when the condition is not satisfied, that is when I have my desired result. Until then, the function will just continue calling itself recursively.

Is my logic correct? I discussed this with someone else, he said it wasn't, but did not explain further.

Comment: The `return` statement needs to be indented so that it's part of the function.

Comment: ohh sorry, in the code it is, I forgot to indent it here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you're asking us about this code. Why not just run it and see how it does? We're not going to be able to test it out (since it's not a [mcve]), so there's not a whole lot of us to contribute.

Comment: @Blckknght I did, and I think it's giving the correct answer. Like I said, someone else I discussed this with though, said the logic was wrong without explaining why. I thought maybe someone with better knowledge who already has prior experience with such a problem could shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Your if statement and your implicite else is your recursion "stopping condition". As soon as the if condition is false, it will exit the function and end recursion by exiting all parent calls.

You have to make sure this statement can be false at least once to avoid a max depth recursion exception.